# scrollPathToVisible does not behave properly

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtree

I have a `JTree` and I want it to scroll down to the latest child entry.

I used `scrollPathToVisible` in the following manner

```
statusTree_.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
```

Where `childNode` is the latest added child to the tree. The problem I have is whenever root is added then the scroll does not move down when the first child is added, but starts moving down only from the second child.

User can observe that there is a gap below in the scroll pane and needs to scroll manually, I need the scroll to move automatically for the first child also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to wrap the `scrollPathToVisible` call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to let all listeners to process add node event and refresh internal structures accordingly.

Comment: Works Perfectly fine, thnak you very much.

Comment: Thanks for such an elegant solution!